# issue in DataGrid when load the items

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql

I tried to load top3 record of table into DataGrid it shows error **Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'string'**.The code below what i wrote

```
MyDatatBaseDataContext Mydb = new MyDatatBaseDataContext();    
var top3 = (from t in Mydb.GetTable<student>() select t).Take(2);
grd_8.ItemStringFormat = top3;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `var top3 = (from t in Mydb.GetTable<student>() select t).Take(2);`

to

```
List<student> top3 = (from t in Mydb.GetTable<student>() select t).Take(2).ToList();
```

and if grd_8.ItemStringFormat is a string then you have to convert yr List to a string using StringBuilder

but You can assign the `List<student> top3` to Your grid ItemsSource/DataSource

Answer (score 0):

> [ItemStringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemstringformat.aspx) Gets or sets a composite string that specifies
>   how to format the items in the ItemsControl if they are displayed as
>   strings.

Why are you assigning the LINQ results to ItemStringFormat. I believe you are looking for the [ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) property

```
grd_8.ItemsSource = top3;
```

Also, to select first three records from the query use `Take(3)` not `Take(2)`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you assigning your results to the ItemStringFormat?

```
grd_8.ItemStringFormat = top3;
```

You need to assign the results to the ItemSource

```
grd_8.ItemSource = top3;
```